# How to access code generated child elements?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, parent-child

I'm used to working with the DOM in web languages and it's fairly simple to access child elements. JavaScript can get the currently clicked element and change a property of a child element even without an assigned ID. How can a similar behavior be achieved in C#?

Here is some sample code that will generate elements programmatically:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //create a StackPanel
    StackPanel myStackPanel = new StackPanel();
    myStackPanel.Margin = new Thickness(20);
    myStackPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;

    //add stackpanel to MainWindow
    this.AddChild(myStackPanel);
    this.SizeToContent = System.Windows.SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;

    //create an array to loop generated items
    int[] myArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

    foreach (int number in myArray)
    {
        //create a border to hold a label
        Border myBorder = new Border();
        myBorder.Width = myBorder.Height = 100;
        myBorder.Background = Brushes.RoyalBlue;
        myBorder.Margin = new Thickness(5);

        //create the label
        Label myLabel = new Label();
        myLabel.Foreground = Brushes.White;
        myLabel.FontSize = 14;
        myLabel.Content = number;
        myLabel.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
        myLabel.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;

        //add label to myBorder
        myBorder.Child = myLabel;

        //add myBorder to myStackPanel
        myStackPanel.Children.Add(myBorder);

        myBorder.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(myStackPanel_MouseDown);
    }
}

private void myStackPanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //add code to get child label and set font to bold
}
```

I'd like to access the child element `myLabel` of the clicked `myBorder`. Any ideas?

Comment: [Border.Child](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.decorator.child.aspx), perhaps? You already know that property (since you use it in your code), so what is the problem?

Comment: @elgonzo I don't think you fully read the question.

Comment: I did read this: *"I'd like to access the child element myLabel of the clicked myBorder. Any ideas?"* (beside the other text above) Yes, i do think i fully read the question...

Comment: @elgonzo can you post a working solution? That can access children. Not elements with one child.

Comment: i think i do not fully understand your problem. Let's clarify: From a user perspective, are you interested about clicking on the label, or is it really about clicking on the border itself (which is like a kind of visible or invisible frame around the labels)?

Comment: I am interested in clicking on a parent element and accessing a child element. For example, there are 3 items in a stackpanel, how can I access a specific child on click? I kept a single child in the sample code for simplicity. My question title asks about code generated child elements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54403/discussion-between-elgonzo-and-mcsharp).

Comment: Just looked at your code. You shouldn't have `myStackPanel.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(myStackPanel_MouseDown);` in a loop

Comment: Yes I forgot to change that. Needs to be the border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the sender to a Border element and retrieve the child. i.e.:

```
private void myStackPanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    StackPanel myPanel = sender as StackPanel;
    Label myLabel;
    foreach(object o in myPanel.Children)
    {
        if (child is Label)
        {
            myLabel = o as Label;
            //do something with label
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if there are two labels in the border inside a grid or stackpanel? This solution will not work. Grids and stackpanels will have children not child. How can those be targeted?

Comment: @MCSharp, you can easily modify the code for StackPanel. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, this does work (`child` needs to be `o`). However all Labels will be selected with this approach. Any way to isolate a specific one?

Comment: Assign tags to your label when creating them, then test for those tags when accessing them.